# Redux toolkit and actions against repetetive code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

my code is long, and repetetive. I should use helper function to cut it and make it more maintainable and readable. I am a React beginner and I have a question. Should I do most of this logic with helpers functions in seperate file with actions or inside slice?

component:

```
const FilterItems: React.FC<FuncProps> = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const content = e.target.value;
    dispatch(
      recipeAction.setFilterType({
        type: props.type,
        set: e.target.checked,
        content: content,
      })
    );
  };

redux slice:
    setFilterType(state, action: PayloadAction<FilterType>) {
          if (action.payload.type === typeOfFiltering.dishType) {
            const chosenType = action.payload.content;
            if (action.payload.set) {
              state.chosenRecipeTypes.push(chosenType);
            }
            if (!action.payload.set) {
              state.chosenRecipeTypes.filter(
                (recipeType) => recipeType !== chosenType
              );
            }
          }
    
          if (action.payload.type === typeOfFiltering.dishLength) {
            const chosenType = action.payload.content;
            if (action.payload.set) {
              state.chosenRecipeLengths.push(chosenType);
            }
            if (!action.payload.set) {
              state.chosenRecipeLengths.filter(
                (recipeType) => recipeType !== chosenType
              );
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: What logic do you want to refactor?

Comment: Redux Slice, should I do data transformation and helpers function inside slice or in seperate actions file

Answer (score 0):

If you need some functionality in few other components make some helpers functions and reuse it in separate component. If you use it just on one place then you don't need to separate...

also try to use switch instead of if with default case on bottom

and for me looks better if you use destructors instead of this

```
            const chosenType = action.payload.content;
```